# insert null value into Database when textbox is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, textbox

I use LINQ to Access DB in my Asp.net page.

I have a form with some textbox and a submit button before user see the form all of the textbox be empty with this code:

```
txtPName.Text =null;
txtPFamily.Text = null;
txtPUsername.Text = null;
txtPPassword.Text = null;
```

and after click button the values insert in Databse, but if a textbox was empty I want `null` value insert in database but insert empty in database:

```
 Users u = new Users()
 {
      FirstName = txtPName.Text,
      LastName = txtPFamily.Text,
      Username = txtPUsername.Text,
      Password = txtPPassword.Text
 };
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want it to be `null`? For me, `null` means it has never been set, `""` means it has been set but left blank intentionally.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). Since `Text` properties never return `null` you can safely check if their Length is 0 (text is empty):

```
Users u = new Users()
{
    FirstName = txtPName.Text.Length == 0 ? null : txtPName.Text,
    LastName = txtPFamily.Text.Length == 0 ? null : txtPFamily.Text,
    Username = txtPUsername.Text.Length == 0 ? null : txtPUsername.Text,
    Password = txtPPassword.Text.Length == 0 ? null : txtPPassword.Text
};
```

If you also want to treat white-spaces as "empty", use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
FirstName = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPName.Text) ? null : txtPName.Text
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` could be better as it would `null` whitespace entries.

Comment: @Oliver: I have already included `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in my answer.

Comment: The check added for Whitespaces is fantastic.This helped me avoid posting one question of mine :) . Upvoted.

Comment: Assumption is the mother of all.... ;) It feels so unnatural to assume text is not null. Imo the second approach is way better practice.

Comment: You can always use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead. However, it is worth nothing(especially because OP tries to set it to null explitely) that in ASP.NET a text is never null. The pattern is always that string.Empty is returned instead then. This is the shortened source(ILSpy, `TextBox.Text`-get): `if (text != null)
  {
   return text;
  }
  return string.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string.IsNullOrEmpty or string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace methods to check your TextBox value.

//This will set a string of your Textbox to either a value (if it has one) or null

`string yourValueToPutIntoDatabase = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourTextBox.Text)) ? yourTextBox.Text : null;`

You could also use it in an if-statement if you are more comfortable :

```
string valueToPutInDatabase;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourTextBox.Text))
{
 //Your textbox was empty
 valueToPutInDatabase = null;
}
else
{
 valueToPutInDatabase = yourTextBox.Text;
}
```

Try this out..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(txtPName.Text==""){
u.FirstName =null;
}
if(txtPFamily.Text==""){
u.LastName =null;
}
if(txtPUsername.Text==""){
u.Username =null;
}
if(txtPPassword.Text==""){
u.Password =null;
}
```